# In kotlin, how to recieve data class in bundle with parcelable?

Tags: kotlin, bundle, parcelable

Send bundle from itemClickListener of Recyclerview in Activity like this

```
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("myPlace", ArrayList<MyPlace>(myPlace))
    ScheduleListFragment().arguments = bundle
    Log.d("번들",bundle.toString())
    finish()
```

and receive bundle in fragment like this

```
val bundle = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList<MyPlace>("myPlace")
if(bundle != null){
val yourPlace = requireArguments().getParcelableArrayList<MyPlace>("myPlace")
Log.d("마이", yourPlace.toString())
        }
```

It says bundle is null...

Comment: I don't see you doing anything with your ScheduleListFragment that you instantiated and set the arguments on. I don't see how it's possible for you to check if it got its bundle if you never performed a Fragment Transaction with it.

Comment: the activity is activated by fragment, so i didnt use transaction

Comment: i solve this with registerForActivityResult!